# How to separate load and install URLs in Shopify

Tags: oauth, shopify

I faced with the problem how can I check which action user did: click "GET" button in the Shopify App store or click on the installed app in his Shopify admin panel. Both these actions goes to one URL that I specified in the settings of my app on the field "App URL (required)". For example, BigCommerce allows specify two different URLs for install and load app.

Also I find one solution but I don't think it good. After loading installed app Shopify send in the request one more field "protocol" which absent in the install request. For now it's only difference that I see.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the second question. But for the first question, "use URL query string parameters"